# Upgrading from SHA1 to SHA2 breaks everything in C# application

Tags: c#, security, sha1, sha256, sha

I have been tasked with **checkmarx** and **whitehat** sentinel security fixes.  Problem is that changing from **SHA1** to **SHA2** doesn't automagically work.  The **new** **Hash** is **NOT** going to match all the hundreds of users **passwords** in the database table.

What am I suppose to do, make everyone **change** their **password**?

C# code change:

```
//SHA1 sha = SHA1.Create();
SHA256 sha = SHA256Managed.Create();

byte[] buff = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(SaltAndPwd));
```

Comment: Hmm, no, a bigger hash does not require a different password.  You only need to recognize the existing password once.  When you have it you can authenticate with the old hash, generate the new hash and delete the old hash.  Don't take security advice from strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Good point and you're not stranger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know well, hashing is one-way which means cannot be decrypted back to original value and nothing can convert without knowing original value. Even SHA2 has 'different' and more advanced hashing algorithm.

One bad option is, marking users differently who were registered before SHA2. However, The users with old SHA1 might be exposed to hacking like LinkedIn site was hacked when using SHA1.

My idea is same with you. Just like when we see Password Change Recommendation in Big internet sites, Just simply make short process like validating old password and get new password from users.

Nuget package like PWDTK which is of SHA2 might help..

Comment: I think the idea of Hans Passant at the comment is right, As of his idea, compare old password with hashed value of user's input and if they're correct, add a code to hash the user's input with SHA2 and update this new hashed value to new column. I'd recommend to make new column because if you use the old password column to save the newly hashed password, the old passwords and new passwords will be mixed and it'll be difficult to know the time point which Upgrading to SHA2 is finished or not. Have nice programming !